# Docker is skipping "@name/package" dependency in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, samba

I tried to turn my NodeJS app into a docker image, but it's skipping one specific dependency of my package.json.

It's some kind of [fork](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@juangm/samba-client), from the [original package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/samba-client). How to include it?

```
{
  "name": "<project>",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Webapp for process simplification",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app",
    "test": "nodemon -r dotenv/config app dotenv_config_path=./.env.tst",
    "prod": "nodemon -r dotenv/config app dotenv_config_path=./.env.prd --watch .env.prd"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@juangm/samba-client": "^1.8.0", <<-- this one
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "dotenv-safe": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.19",
    "mssql": "^6.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "pug": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://<project>.git"
  }
}
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN apt update && apt install smbclient -y
WORKDIR /home/<user>/<project>
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 7000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "prod"]
```

Comment: This isn't a Docker related issue. Docker build and run work as expected. Maybe check your application.

Comment: I think you're right. Running `npm install` in the project directory won't install the module as well.. It's not related to Docker.

Comment: remove '@juangm/' from dependency in .json file